# htaccess mod_rewrite URL within subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My question seems to be unanswered on StackOverflow, so here goes:

I want to rewrite the following URL using an **htaccess** file which is in the root folder.

The URL to rewrite is this:

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/item/12345
```

to this:

```
http://www.domain.com/subfolder/item.php?id=12345
```

However nothing I seem to do works. I can successfully rewrite the item.php URL if it is in the root folder using this:

```
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ item.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

... but not if the item.php file is in a subfolder!

Comment: What does "cannot get it to work" mean? What is in the log files? What happens if you try?

Comment: The first URL doesn't "match" so it does not rewrite. I'm baffled, it seems such a simple question but no-one can solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use following .htaccess in your subfolder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder

RewriteRule ^item/(.*)$ item.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Your rewritten URL would become: `http://domain.com/subfolder/item/123`

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you!! What is first line for?

Comment: That is for disabling `MultiViews`.  Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for sending this URL (The one entered in the browser address bar):

> http://www.domain.com/subfolder/item/12345  (Can be any number) **to** this rewrited URL:
>
> http://www.domain.com/subfolder/item.php?id=12345

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/item/([0-9]+)/?$ subfolder/item.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Those directives will work only if there is a **subfolder** directory and in that directory there is in fact a file **item.php**