# htaccess redirect all urls in directory to index.php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i have script in directory and on root wordpress is running which is creating problems when i try to run script in sub directory , throwing 404 error

my website structure

```
wordpress : /
script    : /Software/
```

my script have urls like

```
> http://www.domain.com/Software/home
> http://www.domain.com/Software/caseForm
> http://www.domain.com/Software/createuser
```

so i want that all urls like above to be redirected to index.php   of software directory

what i tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Software
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

but my current htaccess configuration is throwing me error **No input file specified.**

Comment: D you want any URI values passed to the index.php page?

Comment: Don't know if it helps but maybe you need to add a slash "RewriteBase /Software/"

Comment: @Martin ya want to pass any uri to index.php inside software dir

Comment: @maalls slash not helped , tried it , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some precursory notes:

- The `NC` tag means **N**o **C**ase meaning the tags are case insensitive. Recommended.
- The `QSA` tag means **Q**uery **S**tring **A**ppend meaning things like `?file=filename&horse=neddy` from the original URI are appended to the rewritten URI. May be something you'd need here?

**To solve Your error**:

> No input file specified.

Is caused by various issues and can be solved by tweaking the last line to include a `?` and removing the preceeding slash from the destination directory, so it become:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27291640/3536236))

**Full rewrite:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Software
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Also [review this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13651171/3536236).

Comment: you have to clear your browser cache completely (clear site history) when updating the htaccess file. @user889030

Comment: also I spotted my rewrite has a comment line in it. Updated. @user889030

Comment: tried in private windows , still wordpress 404 pages ... :(

Comment: Read through my source link and see if anything else there fits your criteria. Because you're working in a subfolder of the site you should be aware that the WordPress htaccess of the parent folder will also have an influence over the `mod_rewrite` etc.

Comment: i tried it works but stuck in loop as index.php have login.php incase user not login.
[code]
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /Software
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
[/code]

Comment: Ok @user889030 I've made some tweaks and added a further review answer, does this help?